# Windows with bool tool

Tags: modifiers

I cutted some windows out of a cube by using "union" with bool tool, it worked great. But it does not work on this special wall and I have no idea why. Is it because the wall is diagonally?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

(The image is too big, so I used an external hoster)
https://ibb.co/ggBdsyH

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Make sure all the meshes are manifold. If you are using the fast method, make sure there a no coplanar faces in both objects. (A very small rotation on any axis should suffice)

Comment: How do I make a cube manifold? I can't find any information. 
In the meantime I tried to use the boolean modifier as it is shown in the following tutorial. https://youtu.be/HqutwxCzfjs?t=375
I created two completely new cubes by pressing Shift + A and it happens either nothing or one half of the cut cube unites with the other cube when I delete it. I added a gif above. I am very annoyed. I watched several videos where it everytime worked, but when I do the same, it does not work...

Comment: In short, manifold means that your object may contain some water without leaking anywhere if you rotate it in any direction. In your video, the biggest cube is not manifold since the top has been removed. If you want to make sure an object is manifold, you can either go to select > by trait> non manifold and fix the geometry or enable the 3D-Print toolbox add-on (free and shipped with blender) which provides a neat "Make manifold" operator in its panel

Comment: Also, if you change the method from "Exact" to"Fast" you might see some change in the behaviour

Comment: Thank you very much, that made it very clear for me. :) I made both meshes manifold by using the 3D-print toolbox so there are no coplanar faces (I checked it) but there is still the same effect. :/

Comment: I noticed that 3D-print toolbox reports me an overhang face. I created a new cube and it has an overhang face at the bottom by default. Could this be the reason? I don't see any special at this face even in edit mode. It looks just normal.

Comment: An overhang face is not necessarily a bad thing and it is only relevant to 3D printing, it shouldn't affect boolean operations. See this for more information https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/206057/86891